# API Gateway throwing error on response taking longer than 3000 ms

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway throwing error as follows:
Response Headers

```
Date: Sat, 30 Jan 2021 08:15:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 16
Connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-RequestId: a9933c61-83d1-4ce5-814a-aebb4634d2bc
x-amzn-ErrorType: AuthorizerConfigurationException
x-amz-apigw-id: Z9BOtFf-hcwFdiw=
```

Response Body

```
{"message":null}
```

Here is some more information about the request

```
Status: 500Internal Server Error
Time: 3.18 s
Size: 309 B
```

My setup involves request passing from client to AWS API GATEWAY > NLB > ALB > ECS Cluster Service Task
Response coming back in the same way.
I think this error is being caused because the response is taking more than 3 seconds. But I don't know how to fix it. How to allow responses that take longer than 3000 milliseconds to be allowed without throwing error.

Comment: The error seem to be from some `Authorizer`. What do you use for that? A lambda function?

Comment: Yes. For Authorizer I am using a Lambda Function

Comment: Thanks @Marcin It was helpful. Please add that as an answer and I would love to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by lambda `Authorizer`. The **default lambda timeout** is 3 seconds, which was not enough for the function to complete successful.